# Neo4j limit with non-constant

Tags: neo4j, limit

I want to ask if it is possible to limit nodes returned by one segment of query with non-constant, that mean - I want limit to be dependent on some variable returned by query for example 30% of count of neighbor nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit ugly, but what about something like this?

```
MATCH n-[:type]->(neighbor)
WITH n, toInt(count(neighbor) * 0.3) AS limit
MATCH n-[:type]->(neighbor)
WITH n, collect(neighbor)[1..limit] AS neighbors
UNWIND neighbors AS neighbor
RETURN n, neighbor
```

Comment: Thanks for fast response. But is it needed to do same match 2 times? And also [1..limit] is not wanted I think collections are indexed from 0 so [0..limit]. But thanks for idea, now I'm trying something.

Comment: Good to know, what was the answer that worked for you?

Comment: I partially used  what you posted and changed it for my purpose. The example with 30% of count of neighbors was just an easy example, I needed also to sort that collection by another value first and than limit it using count of neighbor of neighbor etc. Shortly, my problem was little bit wider :) But it can be said that you gave me an idea how to do it. Sometimes my brain does not work properly and need to be pushed little bit :)